# React Native Firebase Storage - getting error when trying to save image with .putFile()

Tags: react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I am trying to save a local image from the phone to firebase storage but am getting the following error.

```
Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/........uid=XXXXX requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

See below code.
`await imageRef.putFile(localUri, {contentType: 'image/jpg'});` is where the issue is occuring

```
const uploadImageAndGetUrl = async (localUri, firebasePath) => {
  try {
    const imageRef = storage().ref(firebasePath);
    await imageRef.putFile(localUri, {contentType: 'image/jpg'});
    const url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
    return url;
  } catch (err) {
    Alert.alert('Profile.js.....Error getting image url from FB', err);
  }
};
```

Manifest is as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution 1:

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'

async function getPathForFirebaseStorage (uri) {
  if (Platform.OS==="ios") return uri
  const stat = await RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(uri)
  return stat.path
}
```

```
const fileUri = await getPathForFirebaseStorage(file.uri)
  const uploadTask = ref.putFile(fileUri)
```

## Solution 2:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'

const data = await RNFS.readFile(uri, 'base64')
await ref.putString(data, 'base64')
```

**Note:** if above solution do not work then make sure `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions from the user using the react-native-permissions library

Comment: Solution 2 worked - thanks!
There was no need to use react-native-permissions

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if its the source path issue or its something about the permission. Have you added the required permissions to the Manifest.xml file.